# Creating a static variable for each child of a base class and getting it

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I have an abstract manager class 'ManagerBase' which I want to derive and have multiple children from it that all have static references.

```
public abstract class ManagerBase<T> : MonoBehaviour {

public static T SharedInstance = default(T);
static bool _sharedInstanceSet = false;

/// <summary>
/// Awake this instance, assigning the shared instance. Important this awake function gets called for each derived class
/// </summary>
protected virtual void Awake() {

    if (_sharedInstanceSet != false) {

        if (BaseManagerVars.ShouldOverwritePrevious == true) {
            Toolbox.GetTools.DestroyObject(SharedInstance.gameObject); //ERROR T does not contain definition of 'gameObject' (FYI is a variable in MonoBehaviour)
        }

        else {

            Toolbox.GetTools.DestroyObject(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Duplicate manager " + this.gameObject.name + " will be deleted");
            return;
        }
    }
    SharedInstance = this;   //ERROR Cannot convert type ManagerBase<T> to T
    _sharedInstanceSet = true;
}
```

Like so

```
public class EventMessageManager : ManagerBase<EventMessageManager>  {

}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to access the shared instance of 'EventMessageManager' by using the inherited variable 'SharedInstance'

like

```
EventMessageManager.SharedInstance.whatever();
```

How might I go about getting this functionality? You can see I have commented in the compile errors to the base manager class.

I was originally using a static variable in the 'MangerBase' like so

```
public static ManagerBase<T> SharedInstance
```

But to get the static references of children was too long and not as neat looking

```
EventMessageManager manager = EventMessageManager.SharedInstance as EventMessageManager;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that using static fields is a good idea from the beginning. Try "SharedInstance = new T;" instead. You will have to enforce a new()-constraint on the generic parameter for this to work.

Comment: All your problem is solved if you change your `SharedInstance` definition as `public static ManagerBase<T> SharedInstance = default(ManagerBase<T>);` but I'm not sure how much this can help you. Or may be you need to write an implict conversion operator from `T` to `ManagerBase<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to do such a pattern (some additional info might help), but the following should work:

```
public abstract class ManagerBase<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : ManagerBase<T>
```

and

```
SharedInstance = this as T;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method getSharedInstance() which returns the shared instance of the type from a dictionary, the problem is that it need a constructor or static init method. like this:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, object> SharedInstances;

public static init()
{
     if (!SharedInstances.ContainsKey(T.getType()))
     {
           SharedInstances.Add(T.getType(), default(T));
     }
}

public static T getSharedInstance()
{
     return (T)SharedInstances[T.getType()];
}
```